# get all options in select from Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

there is a select in the document i.e:

```
<select tabindex="1" size="5" name="abc" multiple>
    <option value>Select a value.</option>
    <option value>option 1</option>
    <option value>option 2</option>
    <option value>option 3</option>
    <option value>option 4</option>
</select>
```

I could do something like below in javascript/typescript:

```
    let select = document.querySelector("select").children;
    for(let i= 0; i<select.length; i++) {
        console.log(select[i].innerHTML);
    }
```

but the same code in Angular 2 class would give me this:

```
<select tabindex="1" size="5" name="abc" multiple>
    <option value>Select a value.</option>
    <option value>__</option>
    <option value></option>
</select>
```

I suspect it might be that Angular 2 ran this before the document is fully loaded. but Angular 2 scripts etc are at the bottom and I have tried running them in

```
window.onload and $(document).ready(...);
```

it still won't give me the options. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't manipulate DOM directly in Angular.

```
@Directive({ selector: 'option' })
export class OptionDirective {}
```

**xxx.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'some-selector'
})
export class SomeComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @ContentChildren(OptionDirective) options: QueryList<OptionDirective>;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    // do something with list items
    // loop through all list of option, then do something you want.
  }
}
```

[@ContentChildren](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ContentChildren-decorator.html)

[QueryList](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/QueryList-class.html)

Comment: I'll accept this answer as an alternative. I've figured out why my method didn't work but I'll take your input as an alternative. Thanks